# uwp checkbox double Tapped

Tags: checkbox, uwp

When UWP sets the `Tapped` event on the parent grid, the child checkbox is automatically checked to be double Tapped.

I want to check the child checkbox as `Tapped` instead of double `Tapped`.

Thank you for your reply.

```
<Grid Background="Black" >
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectDefectImageCommand, ElementName=PART_ItemList}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource WhiteCheckBoxStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: What do you mean by double tapped? Do you mean the Tapped event is being triggered twice?

Comment: double tapped is double click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want are setting the checked state inside the `Grid` `Tapped` event, but the result is overriden because the `CheckBox` checking is also triggered. You can prevent this by setting the `CheckBox` `IsHitTestVisible` property to `false` in which case the checkbox will not generate pointer events and will therefore ignore the tap.